# Can anyone simplify a && b && ( True || c ) to 1?

Tags: math, boolean, logic

I found this in a coursebook and think there might be an error in it since I cannot see how it simplifies to 1, I get AB instead...

[image]

Comment: can you plz give the exact equation you want to simplify.

Comment: It's that second to last line, I don't get how they simply it to 1, the most I can do is simply to AB

Comment: I don’t see De Morgan’s law used here at all. Suddenly the negation just disappears. Or is the first row somehow a “a=b” equation and not “a simplifies to b”? Still doesn’t make sense

Comment: Try to solve without demorgan law

Comment: The book is written badly, the first line where the equal sign is should actually be written over two separate lines. I can work out everything from the first part of the first line all the way to the penultimate line, but I just don't see how it equals 1. True or C will always equal True which leaves AB1 which is AB...

Comment: The first line is wrong, surely? (A' . B')' is (A + B), not (A . B)

Answer (score 0):

being a de morgans law here we consider A=B=C=1 and so A'=B'=C'=0 (A' is A rise to dash)

so L.H.S last statement is = A.B(1+C) = 1.1(1+1) = 1.1 =1
 HERE 1.1 =1 and 1+1 =1 (applying the demorgans law) you may google the use formula

Comment: Where is A=B=C=1 from? I cannot see this in DM's theorems

Comment: so its an assumption that where we consider A=1 likewise A' means negation of A 0 its an boolean logic so i stated A=B=C=1

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't understand though what's making us not make the assumption that A=0? When would we make this assumption that A=1?